# Where does the context of a service declared in the AndroidManifest.xml comes from?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest

I have made a mistake on my app by trying to access the context of a service (that was declared in the `AndroidManifest`) right at its constructor, like this:

```
class MyService : Service() {

    private val myObj = MyObjectThatNeedsContext(this)

    (...)
}
```

I only realized the problem after seeing in the Google Play Console a couple of crashes caused by `NullPointerException`, pointing at the instantiation of `myObj`. So far so good, but my question come from the fact that this crash never happened to me during my tests, and only happened to part of the users, not all. Theoretically it should always crash when trying to instantiate `MyService`, since the context is never available during construction, right? So why does this crash only happen occasionally?

Also, does a crash that happens in the creation of a service declared in the `AndroidManifest` interfere with the usage of the app? What did my app's user saw when this service crashed with a `NullPointerException`?

Thanks.

Comment: `this` is never null, so we'd really need to see what `MyObjectThatNeedsContext` does with the Context that is passed in. Please include that and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Inside `MyObjectThatNeedsContext` it instantiates a `DataStore`, that needs context, and apparently the inner logic that creates the DataStore calls context.getApplicationContext(), which sometimes returns null. Why does it returns null only sometimes?